# How do I add tailwindcss to vite?

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, vite

I'm using [vite](https://github.com/vuejs/vite) `0.16.6` and wanted to migrated a vuepress site to using vite.

However I was unsure how to configure vite to using tailwindcss.

in my `index.css`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After some digging, looks like that we have to include a `postcss.config.js` in the root directory of the application

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    // ...
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
    // ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: doc https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite is missing this part =.="

Comment: putting the `postcss.config.js` in the app root was what fixed it for me. Optionally, you can edit your `vite.config.js` to specify the location of your `postcss.config.js` file. https://vitejs.dev/config/#css-postcss

Comment: I love how after 2 years this answer is still applicable :D

Comment: this worked after i migrated from create-react-app v5 to vite

Answer (score 2):

```
yarn add tailwindcss @tailwindcss/typography @tailwindcss/ui -D
```

`yarn tailwind init` note : you can use npm

crate file : `postcss.config.js` and add :

```
module.exports={
 plugins: [
  require('tailwindcss'),
  require('autoprefixer'),
  ]
 }
```

Replace the contents of src/index.css file with:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a vite tailwind plugin https://github.com/axe-me/vite-plugin-tailwind

it enabled the jit compiler by default and it also have a tailwind config viewer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a vite project that includes tailwind, the [create-vite-tailwind](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-vite-tailwind) initializer package is what you want.

```
$ npm create-vite-tailwind
...
$ npm run dev
```