# Locating Tailwind CSS File

Tags: css, tailwind-css

anyone here use tailwindcss? as a clueless newbie, can someone tell me how you do you access the base css file where changes are being shown. I'm using vite, postcss and autoprefixer.

OR how do I build it?

Comment: library files are located in node modules or vendor folder. however you dont want to edit the tailwind file, if that is the reason you are looking for it. to customize css you write your own that is located after the external, so you override it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add tailwindcss to vite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61949967/how-do-i-add-tailwindcss-to-vite)

Comment: be good to know where they are, copy them and modify them

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you are using Tailwindcss you don't need a separated file. Whenever you are writing a div, you can give its style inside classeName if you are using React. example in React:

```
<div className="bg-white py-6 px-4 md:px-10">
</div>
```

You can also make specifics styles in a separated file and call them inside the divs like CSS but it is not so common.